# Dynamically filtering feature count in QGIS Atlas, Legend

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression, legend, atlas

I was struggling to filter the legend items ( feature count ) , based on the current feature layer. My atlas layer  is a world map layer and the points layer ( that is in being counted in the legend ). The below expression on the QGIS legend expressions is working but super slow . Any better way to do this ?

This is is using the Legend expression button. Works only  with the  Sum / total  button disabled.

```
if (@symbol_label  = 'Remaining', @symbol_label 
 || ' ' || aggregate('Points__ebc6c554_d138_46f5_9280_9d5c1b2dfdbe','count',"ID","Status" = 'Remaining' AND within($geometry,@atlas_geometry))
, @symbol_label 
 || ' ' || aggregate('Points__ebc6c554_d138_46f5_9280_9d5c1b2dfdbe','count',"ID","Status" = 'Planned' AND within($geometry,@atlas_geometry))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, Project and layers are  here   https://github.com/datavantage/gissample/blob/main/Legend3.gpkg   @Babel

Comment: Correct , this is for each atlas feature . As I iterate through the atlas pages, I want the legend to correctly filter the Feature counts. The expression is under the expression button in this image. It will only work if the Sum button is switched off.

Comment: I just added an image , the expression is in the legend settings

Comment: This is great, thank. you @Babel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following expression. Delete your expression from the header, but insert it directly to the legend of the categorised entries if you want to create the number of feautures dynamically in the legend.

*By the way: I changed the point layer name to `Points`:  your name contains spaces what can be a bit tricky. So in the following expression, adapt the layer's name to the one you use.*

But even better would be to create new attributes `Planned` and `Remaining` on your World layer with the same expression and then use this attribute in the legend. Like this, you calculate it once and won't get any slowing down when creating the atlas.

```
array_length(
    overlay_contains (
        'Pointlayer',  -- change layer name
        $id,
        filter:=Status='Planned' -- change to Remaining for the other symbol
    )
)
```

[image]